# Access an S3 bucket created by another user

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cyberduck

Here's my **scenario**: I'm *user Marius*, and all I want to do is to:

1. access an **S3 bucket** created by *user Admin*,
2. upload some images there,
3. access them, via CloudFront, later on.

Here's a summary of my attempts so far:

1. *User Admin*, using the **AWS Management Console** (AWS MC), grants `List`, `Update/Delete`, `View Permissions` permissions for his already created S3 bucket to *User Marius*.
   To grant permissions we used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608941/341929), using for `grantee` first the users email; then the AWS canonical userid, both of them falling back to the username.
2. *User Marius* uses CyberDuck to successfully connect to S3, using `Access Key ID` / `Secret Access Key`, but the root folder is empty. Accessing S3 through AWS MC doesn't help either:

   > To get started using Amazon S3, create a bucket to hold your objects.

The attempt to create a new bucket with the same name -- *as per [Tom Andersen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927018/341929) below* -- fails: the bucket already exists.

[image: Create bucket failed]

What do I have to do to access that S3 bucket and modify it's contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A secret and key only gets you access, you still need to create a bucket, which is basically like creating a new drive letter in windows, adding a new hard drive, etc.

But you sound like someone has given you access. You may have two AWS accounts - one that has no buckets and one that you have been granted access to that has buckets?

Or the people who gave you access want you to make the buckets? If you know the bucket name, trying to make one with the same name will fail if anyone else on earth has already made a bucket by that name.

Comment: The buckets already exist and I know their names. Tried to create a new bucket with the same name (both from the AWS MC and CyberDuck) and failed: http://i.imgur.com/odUcm.png Does this mean that I'm not having proper right over those buckets?

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the Cyberduck Wiki in [Access third party buckets](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#Accessthirdpartybuckets). Just set the default path in the bookmark to the bucket name or choose *Go → Go to Folder…* when connected.